# Android why not use 'this'?

Tags: android

I wonder that, Android source not use 'this'.

Example,

```
private String text;

 ...


 this.text = "t" // This is java style
 text = "t" // This is reference google android code style

 ...
```

Will know what I'm doing wrong?
If not, then do not use this ever wonder why there is.

THANKS.

Comment: It doesn't make any different, you can use both as long as it is instance variable.

Comment: AFAIK, in their code style `private` variables starts with 'm' like `mDescription`

Comment: `// This is java style`. Aha. Where did you get that information?

Comment: Will know what I'm doing wrong? Not java style? sorry:(

Comment: It is possible to always use `this` so some people do it. You can configure your automatic code formatter so it adds (or removes) the superfluous `this`. But it is not part of some standard.

Comment: I understand. I wonder if not part of standard 'this'.

Comment: use 'this' correct? not use 'this' correct? Or that there is no correlation at all?

Comment: "AFAIK, in their code style private variables starts with 'm' like mDescription"
Not private variables, but for member variables. This convention actually comes from C++ bue the Android guys seem to use it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

using 'this' just makes an explicit call to the instance. Its needed if you want to use the objects instance variable when it is hidden by a local variable. For example:

```
class MyClass extends Activity {

    private String text = "myText";

    public void printText()
    {
        String text = "myText2";
        Log.d("MyClass", text); // will print "myText2" to logcat
        Log.d("MyClass", this.text); // will print "myText" to logcat
    }
}
```

In this scenario, this stands for the current instance of MyClass. You can also use MyClass.this for example to get a variable of the MyClass-Object inside an inner-class Object.

Edit:

You dont need to use 'this' if you dont have multiple variables of the same name in different scopes or try to access the variable of an instance from an inner object. However, if you feel confident with it, you can use this whenever you want. Its sometimes good to make the code easy readable.

Comment: "overlapped" should be "hidden".

Comment: I know that. but my question is 'Would that it is right to write "this"'? Related reference do you ever? Thanks reply:)

Comment: If you like it, use it. If u dont, dont use it. Its more a matter of taste and style than about "what if right or wrong".

Answer (score 1):

In non-Android *Java*, `this` is more common, since variable names are often the same as parameter names. For examples:

```
public class Test1 {

    private String text;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test = new Test1();
        test.setText("foobar");
        //...
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

In *Android*, however, it is taught to use variable names such as `mString`, differentiated these global variables from local ones. The same code above, would then look like this on Android:

```
public class Test2 extends Activity {

    private String mString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(BundleSavedInstanceState) {
        setText("foobar");
    }

    public void setText(String string) {
        mString = string;
    }
}
```

In the end, however - this is just about what the developer is comfortable with. If you produce clean, working, readable code, then keep doing that. If not, consider following these guidelines. For instance, I write lots of Android code every day - but I prefer to use the syntax described in the first example.